# React Native Zoomable Sketch Canvas

Tags: react-native

I want to create a `Sketch Canvas` that can be **zoomed** in using `React Native`. For this, I used the `ReactNativeZoomableView` component and included the `SketchCanvas` inside it. This way, I can both zoom and draw on the screen. However, when I zoom in, random lines start appearing in unrelated places as I draw. How can I resolve this issue? Is there another method or feature for creating a Canvas with zoom capabilities that I can use?

```js
<ReactNativeZoomableView
    ref={zoomRef}
    maxZoom={3}
    minZoom={1}
    zoomStep={0.5}
    initialZoom={1}
    pinchToZoomInSensitivity={5}
    pinchToZoomOutSensitivity={5}
    movementSensibility={1}
    panBoundaryPadding={0}
    bindToBorders={true}
    zoomEnabled={isTwoFingerTouch}
    initialOffsetY={150}
>
    <View
        style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: screenHeight,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            marginTop: -150,
        }}>
            <SketchCanvas
                touchEnabled={touchEnable}
                ref={canvasRef}
                style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    zIndex: 100,
                }}
                strokeColor={color}
                strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
              />
              <Text style={{fontSize: 28, color: '#0f0f0f'}}>1. Soru</Text>
              <FastImage
                source={require('../assets/soru1.png')}
                style={styles.backgroundImage}
                resizeMode={
                  Platform.OS === 'ios'
                    ? FastImage.resizeMode.contain
                    : FastImage.resizeMode.contain
                }
              />
              <Text style={{fontSize: 28, color: '#0f0f0f'}}>2. Soru</Text>
              <FastImage
                source={require('../assets/soru1.png')}
                style={styles.backgroundImage}
                resizeMode={
                  Platform.OS === 'ios'
                    ? FastImage.resizeMode.contain
                    : FastImage.resizeMode.contain
                }
        />
    </View>
</ReactNativeZoomableView>
```